# emmeans function won't run or takes too long to run

Tags: r, statistics, linear-regression, covariance

I am new. I want to use the `emmeans` function to calculate estimated marginal means based on a model. This model is done by `lmer` function. The problem is I have lots (20ish) of fixed effect variables and one random effect variable. I can run `lmer` with no problem. By the way I set the 20ish categorical variables as factors before I run the `lmer`. When I use `emmeans`, the error shows

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 49391.4 Gb

I know it is a memory issue. If I use 2-3 variables to build model, the emmeans function will run, although it takes 20 minutes to finish. The dataset is quite big (20 k). Does anyone experience the same thing? Or I should use a different function? Is there anyway to make it work in R? I am a spss user, it seems it does not take spss long to calculate this, I do not understand why I can not run it in R.

My R script looks like this:

```
mod1 <- lmer(overall ~ age + gender + job + a + b + ... + c + (1 | groupcode), data=dat, REML=T)
res1 <- emmeans::emmeans(mod1, specs = "age")
res2 <- emmeans::emmeans(mod1, specs = "gender")
...
```

Follow up:
hi, I have found some free data online, so I can try to replicate the issue. I could not replicate the issue 100%, but it shows the problem that emmeans function takes too long. If I have a bigger dataset and with more variables, it won't run at all. Here are the codes:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

rm(list = ls())

#data source
#http://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/learning/support/datasets/
#bottom of the page: Multilevel ordinal models for examination grades database (zip, 0.9 mb)
#unzip the file and saved under cc:\momeg\
#I used file :a-level-geography.txt


#import data
dat <- read.csv("C:\\momeg\\a-level-geography.txt", header = FALSE,  sep = "")

#assign column names
colnames(dat) <- c("A-SCORE",   "BOARD", "GCSE-G-SCORE", "GENDER", "GTOT", "GNUM", "GCSE-MA-MAX", "GCSE-math-n", "AGE", 
                   "INST-GA-MN", "INST-GA-SD", "INSTTYPE", "LEA", "INSTITUTE", "STUDENT") %>% 
                   tolower(.) %>%
                   str_replace_all(., "-", "_")
#number of records
nrow(dat)

#centering score
dat$'a_score' <- dat$'a_score'- mean(dat$'a_score')



#setup catorgorical variables as factor
dat$gender <- factor(dat$gender)
dat$age <- factor(dat$age)
dat$gcse_g_score <- factor(dat$gcse_g_score)
dat$gcse_math_n <- factor(dat$gcse_math_n)
dat$insttype <- factor(dat$insttype)


library(lme4)
library(emmeans)

#run model

mod1 <- lmer(a_score ~ age + gender + gcse_g_score + gcse_math_n + insttype + (1 | institute), data=dat, REML=T)
summary(mod1)

#get emmean

emm_options(pbkrtest.limit = 50000) #increase the limit to aviod note about d.f to be disabled.

start.time <- Sys.time() #figure out how long it taks r to run the emmeans function
age.means <- emmeans::emmeans(mod1, specs = "age")
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
```

I have run the emmeans function for over an hour now and it is still running. Why it takes so long?

Comment: Hi pink99 and welcome to SO ! Could you share a reproducible example please ? See here for means to do so : [how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: sure. I will come back in a couple of days.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether this does exactly the same thing, but it appears to be similar in the few cases I've tried. The big difference is the degrees of freedom used, `ggpredict()` doesn't use the Kenward-Roger (or any other) correction to the DF.

```
library(lme4)
fm2 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days || Subject), sleepstudy)
emmeans::emmeans(fm2, specs="Days")
# Days emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
# 4.5    299 8.88 25      280      317
# 
# Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
# Confidence level used: 0.95 

library(ggeffects)
m <- mean(sleepstudy$Days)
ggpredict(fm2, terms="Days [m]")

# # Predicted values of Reaction
# # x = Days
# 
#    x | Predicted |   SE |           95% CI
# ------------------------------------------
# 4.50 |    298.51 | 8.88 | [281.11, 315.91]
# 
# Adjusted for:
# * Subject = 0 (population-level)
```

Comment: if K-R is indeed the problem (which seems plausible), perhaps OP could use `lmer.df = "satterthwaite"` ?